# Multiple variable poisson regression using glm() in R: statistics seemingly "independent" of model?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

Consider the following set up:

```
df2 <- data.frame(value = c(10,30, 20,40, 60, 80) %>% as.integer(),
                  cat = c("c1", "c2", "c1", "c2", "c1", "c2"),
                  batch = c("batch1","batch1","batch2", "batch2","batch3", "batch3" ))
```

which generate a dataframe like this:

```
  value cat  batch
1    10  c1 batch1
2    30  c2 batch1
3    20  c1 batch2
4    40  c2 batch2
5    60  c1 batch3
6    80  c2 batch3
```

This represents the type of data I'll be getting. I will receive data from 2 categories (in my case different genotypes of mice), in 3 batches. I was trying to figure out the best way to analyse this data and find out the differences between the 2 categories.

This example is set up in a way so that c2-c1 = 20 in all these 3 batches. In linear regression, factoring batch into the design formula (`formula(value~batch + cat)` vs `formula(value ~ cat)`) is essential for recovering the difference between c1 and c2:

```
> lm(formula = formula(value ~ cat), data = df2) %>% summary()

Call:
lm(formula = formula(value ~ cat), data = df2)

Residuals:
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
-20 -20 -10 -10  30  30 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    30.00      15.28   1.964    0.121
catc2          20.00      21.60   0.926    0.407

Residual standard error: 26.46 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1765,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02941 
F-statistic: 0.8571 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.4069

> lm(formula = formula(value~batch + cat), data = df2) %>% summary()

Call:
lm(formula = formula(value ~ batch + cat), data = df2)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 1.042e-14 -1.042e-14 -1.095e-14  1.095e-14  5.344e-16 -5.344e-16 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.000e+01  1.235e-14 8.097e+14   <2e-16 ***
batchbatch2 1.000e+01  1.513e-14 6.612e+14   <2e-16 ***
batchbatch3 5.000e+01  1.513e-14 3.306e+15   <2e-16 ***
catc2       2.000e+01  1.235e-14 1.619e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.513e-14 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 4.954e+30 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In summary.lm(.) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

However, when I tried to do the same thing with `glm(familiy = poisson())`, things got weird: `batch` turned out to be irrelevant!! `catc2` has the same coefficient and std.

```
> glm(formula = formula(value~cat), data = df2, family = poisson()) %>% summary()

Call:
glm(formula = formula(value ~ cat), family = poisson(), data = df2)

Deviance Residuals: 
     1       2       3       4       5       6  
-4.246  -3.058  -1.945  -1.466   4.814   3.899  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   3.4012     0.1054  32.267  < 2e-16 ***
catc2         0.5108     0.1333   3.831 0.000128 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 86.847  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 71.686  on 4  degrees of freedom
AIC: 107.62

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> glm(formula = formula(value~batch + cat), data = df2, family = poisson()) %>% summary()

Call:
glm(formula = formula(value ~ batch + cat), family = poisson(), 
    data = df2)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6  
-1.3750   0.9692  -0.5373   0.4038   1.0118  -0.8137  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.7081     0.1787  15.152  < 2e-16 ***
batchbatch2   0.4055     0.2041   1.986 0.046993 *  
batchbatch3   1.2528     0.1793   6.988  2.8e-12 ***
catc2         0.5108     0.1333   3.831 0.000128 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 86.8467  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  4.9676  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 44.899

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

This behaviour stays even when I randomized the values as following:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(value = runif(n = 6, min = 10, max=100) %>% as.integer(),
+                   cat = c("c1", "c2", "c1", "c2", "c1", "c2"),
+                   batch = c("batch1","batch1","batch2", "batch2","batch3", "batch3" ))
> df2
  value cat  batch
1    61  c1 batch1
2    10  c2 batch1
3    50  c1 batch2
4    28  c2 batch2
5    71  c1 batch3
6    72  c2 batch3
> glm(formula = formula(value~cat), data = df2, family = poisson()) %>% summary()

Call:
glm(formula = formula(value ~ cat), family = poisson(), data = df2)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6  
 0.0428  -5.2295  -1.4129  -1.4940   1.2915   5.1482  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.10539    0.07412  55.385  < 2e-16 ***
catc2       -0.50353    0.12077  -4.169 3.06e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 77.688  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 59.750  on 4  degrees of freedom
AIC: 97.008

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> glm(formula = formula(value~batch + cat), data = df2, family = poisson()) %>% summary()

Call:
glm(formula = formula(value ~ batch + cat), family = poisson(), 
    data = df2)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6  
 2.3794  -3.7171   0.1975  -0.2573  -1.9917   2.3481  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.78993    0.12710  29.819  < 2e-16 ***
batchbatch2  0.09403    0.16403   0.573    0.566    
batchbatch3  0.70016    0.14518   4.823 1.42e-06 ***
catc2       -0.50353    0.12077  -4.169 3.06e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 77.688  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 29.064  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 70.322

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can point out what's wrong.

Comment: 1. With `lm` you (implicitly) use an identity link. In the Poisson GLM you use (the default and standard) log link. 2. In the Gaussian model you assume that variance is independent of the expected value, in the Poisson model you assume variance equals the expected value. I'm baffled why you expect the same significance results from both models. Following that logic, we wouldn't need GLMs and could always use the much simpler Gaussian models.

Comment: I agree with you that lm and glm should not give the same values. What I could not figure out was when using `glm`, why the 2 designs, `value~cat` and `value ~ batch + cat` would yield **exactly** the same statistics for `catc2`.

Comment: Because you don't have an interaction.